# Changing colors balls

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are three boxes with balls in them:

$$\text{First box - 13 red balls}$$
$$\text{Second box - 15 green balls}$$
$$\text{Third box - 17 blue balls}$$

You can get one ball in a hand and you should get always exactly 2 balls (one for your left hand and one for your right hand).

1. If you have balls from same color in your left and right hand just return them in the box.
2. If you have balls with different colors in your hands paint them in the third color and return them in the third's color box.

**For Example:**

**Pick 1**: If you get one red ball in your left hand and one red ball in your right hand just return them in the red box.
You will be at the end of first picking with:
$$\text{First box - 13 red balls}$$
$$\text{Second box - 15 green balls}$$
$$\text{Third box - 17 blue balls}$$

**Pick 2**: If you get one red ball in your left hand and one blue ball in your right paint them in green and return them in green box.

You will be at the end of first picking with:
$$\text{First box - 12 red balls}$$
$$\text{Second box - 17 green balls}$$
$$\text{Third box - 16 blue balls}$$

**You can pick balls as many times as you want.**

**The questions are:**

```
 1. Is it possible to have the same number balls in each box?

 2. Is it possible to have two boxes with same number of balls?

 3. Is it possible all balls to become in one color (to be in one box)?
```

My Answers to the three questions are NO. However, they are based just on trying to get all the balls in one box or to have two boxes with the same number of balls.

How can I approach this mathematically and is No the correct answer to the three questions?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: This is not quite clear. I'm not sure how much of that is a language issue – if you have the opportunity to go over this with someone with a better command of English, that might help. a) Where you say "pick two balls in each hand", it appears you mean "pick two balls, one in each hand"? b) Presumably where you write "bow" you mean "box"? c) The role of the boxes is not clear. You don't describe the initial number of balls in each box, and it seems that it can't change since the balls are always returned to their box.

Comment: From parts of what you write, I get the impression that you actually mean that the balls are sorted into boxes according to their colours, so the boxes would just be a different way of talking about the colours. Is that correct? Otherwise, please clarify the role of the boxes.

Comment: Thank you both. I have modified the question. Hopefully now it is clearer. 

The boxes are just added by me to have some kind of a container for the balls. The main idea is that we have three groups of balls with three different colors

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081761/drawing-balls-of-an-urn-probability-of-one-colour-run-out-with-replacement)

Comment: This would be a lot easier to understand if there were only one box. Even the questions would become simpler: "*the same number of each color*", "*the same number for two colors*", and "*all balls the same color*".

Answer (score 2):

Consider the three numbers mod $3$.

Originally, they are $13,15,17$, so the numbers mod $3$ are $0,1,2$, in some order.

Every step of changing colors can be described as follows: first reduce each number by $1$, then add $3$ to one of the numbers.

From this description, it should be clear that after any number of steps, the three numbers mod $3$ will remain $0,1,2$, in some order.

This means that no two numbers will ever be equal, which gives answer "no" to your second question; it consequently implies answers "no" to the first and third question (as they are special cases of the second question).

Comment: Thank you. This explains how I can proof the obvious from the excel table that I made.